# Form Application VB.NET File.Create Method, Access Denied to Path

Tags: vb.net, access-denied

I wrote an application which parses a website and downloads an mp4 file from website. User can select the path where he wants to download the video.

When I try to download I get an exception for the file, `Access Denied to Path`. When I gave the permissions to folder that I chose, then works fine.

How can I resolve that problem? End-User will select the folder. How do I change the permissions? or any other solution ?

Comment: Help the user to pick a writable directory, use Environment.GetFolderPath() to set a good SaveFileDialog.InitialDirectory value.

Comment: what if user chooses another directory for example "D:\" or a new folder in some location? He will choose a path, then I save the file in that directory. But when I try to create the file, it says "Access denied"

Comment: So what?  There are lots of reasons why creating a file may fail.  Disk full, file locked, drive type, disk removed, Windows permissions, CAS permissions, network down, etc.  Stuff you can't find out until you actually create the file.  Just tell her about it in a friendly worded message.  Be sure to display Exception.Message, don't just say "it didn't work".  Only she will know what to do about it.

Comment: Besides, D:\ being an optical drive could well be a valid choice.  Burn to DVD feature for example.

Comment: haha D:/ is interesting yeah :) But I'm curious about, i.e. flashget. We install the program then it downloads everywhere (create files, folders.) I want to provide my program like that

Answer (score 1):

The end-user can only select a folder that he has write access to.

You're asking to destroy the Windows security model.

Comment: I mean the end-user will select a folder then I will download the file to this folder. For download, I have to create a file, therefore I need permission for that folder. But I do not know how can I take that permission in runtime

Comment: You cannot get permission if you don't have it.  You're still asking to destroy the Windows security model.

Comment: Well, is there any folder which is public(a folder I can create a file) in Windows to download a file with my program?

Comment: The user's MyDocs or AppData folder, or temp.

Comment: Thanks for replying. How a program save a file to where ever I want? i.e. Photoshop or a download program, flashget ???

Comment: **You can only write to a directory if you have write access**.  You cannot magically steal write access.

Comment: I am not talking about steal. I am saying that how my program can have this permission?  How can I write a code to ask user to give me permission to create a file like a flashget? How flashget create a file ?

Comment: **You can only write to a folder if the user has write access to that folder**.  This applies to _all_ programs.